# Trouble applying StandardScaler() in preparation for Keras NN

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

df =

```
df_train_x.head()
Out[43]: 
      longevity_endfy18      ...       memc_err_law
1029                  9      ...                  0
79                    9      ...                  0
1464                  9      ...                  0
2620                  3      ...                  0
808                   3      ...                  0

type(df_train_x)
Out[44]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

normalizer = preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit(df_train_x)
trainx_norm = normalizer.transform(df_train_x) 
testx_norm = normalizer.transform(df_test_x)
```

I'm trying to apply the standardscaler and am getting this error:

```
normalizer = preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit(df_train_x)
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

On my journey to using Keras, I never thought this would be the hardest part. I've looked at many examples and can't see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are parenthesis missing behind `StandardScaler`.

`normalizer = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(df_train_x)`